# Regex groups for cloudinary url

Tags: javascript, regex, cloudinary

I'm trying to capture different parts of a url while ignoring parts that sometimes comes up.

I've tried using and extending the regex found here with little luck. https://gist.github.com/ahmadawais/9813c44b7e51c2c3540d2165d6c6cc65

Take the example

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/test-site/image/upload/v1619174590/folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg

https://res.cloudinary.com/test-site/image/upload/ar_1:1,c_fill,f_auto,g_auto,w_700/v1619174590/folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg

https://res.cloudinary.com/test-site/image/facebook/fb_id
```

res.cloudinary.com : **host**

test-site : **cloudname**

upload/facebook: **resource_type**

v1619174590/rg/collective/media/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg: **id**

I need to ignore everything between /upload/ and /v, I've accomplished this using //upload/.*?\b(?=v1)/ , but it doesn't account for if the resource type is facebook and there is no /v123

Comment: It is not quite clear, do you mean you want `https?:\/\/(?<host>[^\/]+)\/(?<cloudname>[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/(?<resource_type>[^\/]+)(?:\/[^\/,]*,[^\/]*)?\/(?<id>.*)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hnCGHF/3). That is, excluding a part with a comma in it right after `resource_type`.

Comment: Seems your demo is working in the cases I've tested so far on my end.

Comment: Great, I posted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67438427/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
https?:\/\/(?<host>[^\/]+)\/(?<cloudname>[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/(?<resource_type>[^\/]+)(?:\/[^\/,]*,[^\/]*)?\/(?<id>.*)
https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+\/([^\/]+)(?:\/[^\/,]*,[^\/]*)?\/(.*)
```

The first regex is compliant with the ECMAScript 2018+ standard that supports named capturing groups, and the second one just contains regular, numbered capturing groups.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hnCGHF/3).

*Details*

- `https?:\/\/` - `https://` or `http://`
- `([^\/]+)`  - Group 1 (host): one or more chars other than `/`
  - `\/`  - a `/` char
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 2 (cloud name): one or more chars other than `/`
- `\/[^\/]+\/`  - `/`, any one or more chars other than `/` and a `/`
- `([^\/]+)` - Group 3 (resource type): one or more chars other than `/`
- `(?:\/[^\/,]*,[^\/]*)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[^\/,]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` and `,`
  - `,` - a comma
  - `[^\/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*)` - Group 4 (id): the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your question is specific to Cloudinary URL format. If that is correct, the URL format will follow this pattern:

1. Protocol (http or https)
2. Domain (res.cloudinary.com)
3. Cloud name / Sub-Account name
4. Resource type (image, video or raw)
5. Visibility (upload, authenticated)
6. Transformation (or chained transformations)
7. Version number
8. Path to your resource also called as public-id in Cloudinary terms
9. Extension (note that extension is not considered part of public-id in Cloudinary)

In your example URL https://res.cloudinary.com/test-site/image/upload/ar_1:1,c_fill,f_auto,g_auto,w_700/v1619174590/folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg, this would map as follows:

1. https - protocol
2. res.cloudinary.com - domain
3. test-site - cloud name
4. image - resource type
5. upload - visibility (ie a public asset)
6. ar_1:1,c_fill,f_auto,g_auto,w_700 - transformation
7. v1619174590 - version number
8. folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza
9. jpg - extension. Without *f_auto*, the result would have been a JPG image.

Using this logic, the regex to catch most URLs would be as follows:

```
(https?)\:\/\/(res.cloudinary.com)\/([^/]+)\/(image|video|raw)\/(upload|authenticated)\/(.*)\/(v[0-9]+)\/(.+)(?:\.[a-z]{3})?
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by `akshayranganath` is correct but it misses few edge cases.

This modified `regex` handles all cases as below:

```js
/(https?)\:\/\/(res.cloudinary.com)\/([^/]+)\/(image|video|raw)\/(upload|authenticated)\/(?:(.*)\/)?(?:(v[0-9]+)\/)?(.+)(?:\.[a-z]{3})?/gm
```

- https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1675771119/serverless_vs_traditional_infra_83744bc14e.webp
- https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/ar_1:1,c_fill,f_auto,g_auto,w_700/v1619174590/folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg
- https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1619174590/folder/path/cjtdn73cleqagpy4fqza.jpg
- https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/ar_1:1,c_fill,f_auto,g_auto,w_700/site_bg_bright_small.jpg

Checkout the regex101 validation page: https://regex101.com/r/7R2Exu/1